# Iterating over table with Drivermanager

Tags: java, postgresql, grails

I connected with DriverManager to my database and I want to iterate over the rows of a table ,I saw that there is getString method and here how it is used

```
   ResultSet rez=stmtSource.executeQuery(sql);
  while(rez.next()){
  String x =rez.getString("column_name");
  System.out.println(x);
    }
```

- by a given query you get an object ResultSet in which you iterate and extract the information with the getString method,however the method accepts only 1 column name.My question is what if I want to iterate over entire rows and the even compare them?I don't see this functionality ,does anyone have idea how can I overcome that? ;

Answer (score 0):

You use `rez.next()` to iterate through the result set.

Answer (score 0):

> what if I want to iterate over entire rows

What do you think `ResultSet.next()` does?  Hint: if you're uncertain, [read its docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html)!

> and the even compare them?

What does it mean to compare whole rows?  That's a rhetorical question, of course.  Whatever it means *to you* is specific to you and / or your particular purpose.  You can retrieve the values of any number of columns of each row before you move on to the next, and do whatever you want with them.  That includes performing whatever kind of comparisons you like.

However, do consider that a DBMS's whole purpose in (figurative) life is to store and manipulate tabular data.  It is very often both easier and more efficient to make it do as much of the data processing as possible, instead of loading the data into Java and manipulating it there.  This is especially the case if the manipulations to be performed involve reducing or filtering the data that need to be forwarded on to a UI or to subsequent processing.

> I don't see this functionality ,does anyone have idea how can I overcome that?

Visit your optometrist for a stronger eyeglass prescription?